# How to make website responsive according to different size of device?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, size, resolution

How can I make my website responsive according to the different device sizes?

Different laptops and PCs have different resolutions. In that case, if I use media query and
apply it for a particular device( in pixels ) then it will not apply for a different device having
different resolution.

[image]

Let's say, I am using this website(this is just an example) on one pc and it is working but if I use this same website in a different pc with a different resolution then the margin between the Website Type and Number of Results vanishes and they overlap each other.

Please tell me a solution so that when I run a website on a different device with different resolution, it
can run.

Comment: Just use ```media queries```. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use bootstrap framework, by default it has responsive feature other wise you must apply media query every break point.

see this article to learn media query and breakpoints

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-media-queries-breakpoints-media-types-standard-resolutions-and-more/

Comment: I am not allowed to use bootstrap framework. Also, how can I know the breakpoin for every device?

Comment: just click the link i shared it